# reading a file from hadoop using java :no output

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to read and write the file from HDFS. First ,I am trying to read it and display it on console. It runs without giving any error, warning  but also it is not printing the data from the file on console, My file is already saved in hdfs , I can see it on user interface. I think there is some problem with the path I have given, I am not sure as I am connecting hadoop first time to java .I am using eclipse as IDE. Can somebody look into this?

I also tried giving 50075 port number for the name node but this also did not work.

Edit: ***Can anybody tell me how to give right path in java for accessing a file stored in hdfs?***

I am getting this Exception

File file:/localhost:54310/user/hduser/project11/a.txt does not exist.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/localhost:54310/user/hduser/project11/a.txt does not exist.

```
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:397)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:251)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:427)
at newclassentry.main(newclassentry.java:16)
```

There is a problem related to path but I do not know what will be the right path.

On the localhost namenode I am accessing it in /user/hduser/project11 folder.
The file is not empty.
Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class newclassentry {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            Path pt = new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/project11/a.txt");
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
            conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));

            String line;
            line = br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May you got an exception which you can`t see. please add `system.err.println` to `}catch(Exception e){
                }`

Comment: How can you know either you are getting an exception or not, you are not doing anything with catch.

Comment: Thanks Jens, There is an exception Wrong FS: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/project11/a.txt, expected: file:///                                                             and when I replaced hdfs:// with file:///...it gives fillowing:
File file:/localhost:54310/user/hduser/project11/a.txt does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

We need to add core-site.xml for accessing through hdfs
conf.addResource(new Path(Vars.HADOOP_HOME +"/conf/core-site.xml"));

Thanks everybody for locating the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no display on the console and you are sure file is not empty, it means there is error in opening the file which is due to the invalid path of the file.

You need to replace the empty catch block :

```
catch(Exception e){
                }
```

with allowing to print the stack trace so you can see the error occuring.

```
catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav ,I have attached the exceptions.You are right the problem is with path,but I am not getting anywhere how to give right path for accessing a file from hdfs.

Comment: @user3714726 It would be good if you add the complete stack trace.